# imprimir conteúdo de div noutra página

Tags: php, html, css

Tenho uma página de php que recebe valores de um formulário (post) e queria imprimir esse resultados em papel.

Acontece que ao clicar no botão o valor no textarea não aparece na impressão.

Na página de origem tenho este formulário com textarea e um botão para imprimir, assim:

```
<form method="post">
<p><textarea name="textoImprimir" cols="" rows="" class="anamnese-tarea">quero imprimir este texto que acabei de digitar.</textarea></p>
<p><iframe src="imprimir.php" name="frame1" style="display:none;"></iframe>
   <input type="button" onclick="frames['frame1'].print()" value="print!"></p>
</form>
```

Na página imprimir.php tenho assim:

```
<?php
$textoImprimir = $_POST['textoImprimir'];
?>    
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Imprimir</title>
<style>
html, body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; }
.fundo { background: url(../_imagens/fundo_print.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 15mm 15mm 15mm 15mm;
}

table { top:18%; bottom:20%; position:absolute; }
</style>
</head>
<body class="fundo">
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="20%" align="center" valign="middle">ALGUM TEXTO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="80%" align="justify" valign="top"><?php echo $imprimir;?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere o form de impressão para ser dessa forma, assim passaremos via POST, para que possamos fazer a impressão no arquivo imprimir.php

```
<form method="post" action="imprimir.php" enctype="multipart-form/data">
    <textarea name="textoImprimir" id="textoImprimir" cols="" rows="" class="anamnese-tarea">quero imprimir este texto que acabei de digitar.</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Imprimir!">
</form>
```

Dentro do imprimir.php você poe

```
<script>window.print();</script>
```

E troque

```
$textoImprimir = $_POST['textoImprimir'];
```

por

```
$imprimir = $_POST['textoImprimir'];
```

Comment: isso mesmo, coisa mais simples... no fim da página adicionei o encaminhamento para a pagina de origem (independentemente se imprimir, salvar para pdf ou cancelar) e ficou perfeito. Obrigado.

Comment: deparei-me com um problema: se eu adicionar css ou mesmo uma imagem na página imprimir.php, já não funciona. Tem como contornar isto?

Comment: Você adicionou de que forma Pedro?

Comment: André, na outra página coloquei uma tabela e no meio da célula uma imagem, assim: <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:#666 thin solid;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="bottom"><img src="imagem.png" width="100" height="100" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>